The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object in C# on the .NET framework
I'm trying to update an Excel sheet "Customers" and the sheet exists in the Excel file (the file in on an Ubuntu server). But when I'm trying to connect to the file via OLEDB, I get an error:

The Microsoft Access Database engine could not find the object "Customers"

I tried to use $ in the update statement, but I got the same error.
I also checked that I have the right permissions to access the file on the server side.
I'm using this provider: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
My connection string is:
$@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ={" +DataSource + "};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0'"

DataSource is:    "\\serverIP\\home\\data\\fileName.xlsx
string editString = "update [Customers$] set Name = '"+ gunaLineTextBox2.Text + "', phone ='"+ gunaLineTextBox3.Text + "', CSer1 ='"+ Stype1 + "', MainM3u ='"+ Murl + "', CSer2 ='"+ Stype2 + "', BackM3u='"+ Burl + "', CSer3 ='"+ Stype3 + "', secretM3u ='"+Surl+ "', Ex = '"+ gunaLineTextBox4.Text + "', notes='"+ gunaLineTextBox11.Text + "' where id ='"+id+"'";

SqlHelper.botEdit(editString, @"\\serverIP\home\data\m3u.xlsx", 0);

public static void botEdit(string editString, string DataSource, int x)
{
     try
     {
         OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
         OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection($@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ={" +DataSource + "};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0'");// Xml;HDR=YES;

         con.Open();
         com.Connection = con;
         com.CommandText = editString;
         com.ExecuteNonQuery();

         if (x > 1)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Done");
         }

         con.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex) 
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}


Good day to learn about parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Change the connection string to ...;Data Source={DataSource};...

Hi steve .... but I'm using the same connection string that you mention

I'm confused. Do you want to use interpolated strings or do you want to stitch it together using "+"? Right now, it looks like it's in between.

Ok .... In the code above is between curly brackets now Im using this :OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection($@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ={DataSource};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'");

You seem confused about how to construct a connection string. You should choose either of these options:
Interpolated string:
string datasource = @"\\serverIP\home\data\fileName.xlsx";
string connectionString = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ={DataSource};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0'";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

Concatenated string:
string datasource = @"\\serverIP\home\data\fileName.xlsx";
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="+DataSource+";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0'";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

The curly brackets are not part of the connectionstring, they are there to signal an interpolated value.
And also parameterize your query instead of constructing it from unvalidated user controls.

I did both I ve go this error "faulier creat file"

any help ? I have the same problem

Sorry, there were too many backslashes. Only the serverip should have double.

It's okey .... I have the same error even if I used the double backslashes only for the serverip

It seems like ... I could connect to the server but I could not find the file and I really have it on the server and the permissions are set up too
